# How Can I Get the Current URL in a VisualFLow

Tags: visual-flows

Can anyone please suggest how to get the Current URl in a Visual flow.

Comment: Please give a bit more context of why you need the URL in a flow? You can get the record id of a record that you start the flow from or create in the field and then go back to the calling record or a newly created record.

Comment: I need to get the URL in the flow to determine whether it is community or Crm. I wanted to display different Welcome MEssages to Community and Crm. Is there any way that I get the current URl using $Api (in formula) ?  What is $Api.Partner_Server_URL_260 for . Can I use this ?

Comment: Ok, now it is clearer - on a login flow. It might be possible to use the current user's details instead of the url as community users are 'network users'. or would it be specific to a community if you have more than 1 community live.

Comment: I would like to make it specific to a community. Because there may be users who can be members of 1 or more communities. How Do I achieve this.? What exactly is $Api.Partner_Server_URL_260  ?